# Needs to select design pattern to make my Java EE app

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I am creating my final year project in Java EE. In my project there will be users, communities (of type Institutes, Schools, Tutors, Clubs), Questions.

I have desined the front end and database according to my needs. Now i want to make my project on design patterns. Can you please tell me which design pattern will be best for me according to current Java EE apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look on MVC. Try Spring MVC for example.

Comment: If the OP is already using Java EE and wants to experiment with MVC, then an easier choice is to take advantage of JSF that is already there.